# Can similar apps be uploaded on Apple Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, applications

I have uploaded 2 similar apps with different colors,name,icons.
ios team rejected my latest app upload giving the following reason:

Guideline 4.3 - Design
We noticed that your app provides the same feature set as other apps submitted to the App Store; it simply varies in content or language, which is considered a form of spam.

Is it possible to upload similar app with different developer accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to upload an app that already is very similar to existing apps.

Yes, you're probably getting rejected because both apps are under the same dev account.  You could try 'reviewer roulette' and see if you submit under another dev account that another reviewer will approve it. That's unlikely based on how the App Store has been cracking-down on apps such as yours (that are very similar to other apps).

My recommendation is not to do this.  Add the items from the second app into the first app.